# Does yum check for updates?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum

Coming from `apt-get` package manager in Ubuntu I find it kind of odd that I never see any updates when I use `yum`.

On my Ubuntu desktop I almost daily have new available updates when I use `apt-get update` but when I type `yum update` on my Fedora server I always get:

```
[root@pidora ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No packages marked for update
```

So how do I check if it is even working correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Doing `yum update` is enough. It does all what is needed.

What version of Fedora are you using? I guess it is Fedora 21 or older, since the newer ones have `dnf` package manager instead of `yum`. Fedora 21 just entered EOL (end of life), so there are no more updates for this release. You are advised to update to newer one to get security updates.

Comment: That explains a lot. I am using a Fedora Raspberry pi remix called Pidora, it's already the latest but I think it's Fedora 20 based.

Comment: You can find out using `uname -a` what is the base. Maybe Pi has some other repositories, but the officials for Fedora 20 are shut down for some half a year.

Comment: `Linux pidora.local 3.12.23-2.20140626git25673c3.rpfr20.armv6hl.bcm2708 #1 PREEMPT Fri Jul 4 16:06:10 EDT 2014 armv6l armv6l armv6l GNU/Linux` does this pose any security threats?

Comment: I don't have outline about the whole system nor about the raspberry builds. This was general Fedora question with general Fedora answer. Unfortunately it looks like there is no newer Pidora. All the security depends on the use cases you want to use it for, but it is completely different question.

Comment: The Pi situation is unfortunate; we really hope that in the future, all of the changes needed to make the hardware work get upstreamed so it just works with _normal_ Fedora for ARM.